# get address (zipcode) auto geolacate using bing map api?

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation, bing-maps, bing

How to get address (zipcode) auto geolacate using bing map api?

found this code below but not working

```
        $.ajax({
        url: 'http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/' + latitude + ',' + longitude,
        data: {
            o: 'xml',
            key: BingMapsKey
        },
        jsonp: "jsonp",
        success: function (data) {
            //Process the result
        },
        error: function(){
            //Process the error
        }
    })
```

Does anyone know how to accomplish it? Thank you in advance for working examples

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing the dataType parameter. Take a look at this documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/mt793281.aspx It has a jQuery example for accessing the Bing Maps REST Services.

Comment: Well what latitude/longitude values are you passing in. There may not be any address information available for that location.

Comment: getting auto geolocate for latitude/longitude to get the zip code

Comment: if the coordinate isn't within about 150 meters of a road, It's unlike the reverse geocoding service will return any data.